# How do I remove duplicate items from observable array based on multiple properties?

Tags: rxjs, duplicates

If I have an array of items like

```
[
   {id: 1, name: 'Sam', gender: 'boy'}, 
   {id: 2, name: 'Mary', gender: 'girl'}, 
   {id: 3, name: 'Sam', gender: 'boy'}
]
```

Matching on just name and gender, how do I reduce it to the following result?

```
[
   {id: 1, name: 'Sam', type: 'boy'}, 
   {id: 2, name: 'Mary', type: 'girl'}
]
```

Comment: You should probably specify what the actual behavior should be. Should the first element be stored if a similar one (based on name and gender) be stored or the one with the smaller ID?

Answer (score 1):

Let try

```
items$.pipe(map(this.uniqueArray))

uniqueArray(array: any[]): any[] {
    return array.filter(
      (item, index, self) =>
        index === self.findIndex((x) => x.name === item.name)
    );
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isqjpa?file=src/app/hello.component.ts